# Minimum rights required to add a member to SQLAgentUserRole

Tags: sql, sql-server

SQL Server 2012. Don't have sysadmin. Have server control and can get other rights but not sysadmin. What are the minimum rights I need to add a members to SQLAgentUserRole.

```
ALTER ROLE [SQLAgentUserRole] ADD MEMBER [mydomain\myuser]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189775.aspx

> To run this command you need one or more of these permissions or memberships:
>
> •ALTER permission on the role
>
> •ALTER ANY ROLE permission on the database
>
> •Membership in the db_securityadmin fixed database role

So the minimum permission would be ALTER on the role.

```
GRANT ALTER ON ROLE::[RoleName] TO [User Name]
```